# Changing a value of another column based on another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Index    Latitude    Longitude    Wave Height    Wave Period
0        7.101       101          0.3            4.1
1        7.103       101          0.25           4.2
2        7.105       101          0.5            4.4
3        0           0            0.6            4.6
4        0           0            0.7            4.8
5        7.1         101          0.3            4.1
6        7.1         101          0.3            4.3
7        7.1         101          0.3            4.4
8        0           0            0.6            4.6
9        0           0            0.7            4.8
10       7.1         101          0.3            4.1
```

I want to change Wave Height and Wave Period value to zero if Latitude and Longitude equals to zero.

Desired output:

```
Index    Latitude    Longitude    Wave Height    Wave Period
0        7.101       101          0.3            4.1
1        7.103       101          0.25           4.2
2        7.105       101          0.5            4.4
3        0           0            0              0
4        0           0            0              0
5        7.1         101          0.3            4.1
6        7.1         101          0.3            4.3
7        7.1         101          0.3            4.4
8        0           0            0              0
9        0           0            0              0
10       7.1         101          0.3            4.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pd.loc`:

```
df.loc[df['Latitude'].eq(0) & df['Longitude'].eq(0),
       ['Wave Height', 'Wave Period']] = 0
```

Output:

```
Index   Latitude  Longitude  Wave Height    Wave Period
    0      7.101        101         0.30            4.1
    1      7.103        101         0.25            4.2
    2      7.105        101         0.50            4.4
    3          0          0         0.00            0.0
    4          0          0         0.00            0.0
    5      7.100        101         0.30            4.1
    6      7.100        101         0.30            4.3
    7      7.100        101         0.30            4.4
    8          0          0         0.00            0.0
    9          0          0         0.00            0.0
   10      7.100        101         0.30            4.1
```

Answer (score 0):

use numpy function  np.where

```
import numpy as np
df["Wave Height"]=np.where((df["Latitude"]==0) & (df["Longitude"]==0),0,df["Wave Height"])
df["Wave Period"]=np.where((df["Latitude"]==0) & (df["Longitude"]==0),0,df["Wave Periods"])
```